# Mocking vue component dependencies

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I'm trying to run a unit test in which I make an axios call and this returns an error. I have managed to mock the call successfully but on error I call an dependency on an external library (vue-toasted) to display an error message.

When my unit test hits toasted it is 'undefined':

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'error' of undefined

    this.$toasted.error('Search ' + this.searchString + ' returned no results', etc.....
```

I have attempted to register this dependancy in my test wrapper as such

```
import Toasted from 'vue-toasted';

jest.mock(Toasted);
```

these don't seem to provide the wrapper with the correct dependency. Here is my test:

```
it('searches users via axios and returns 404', async () => {
    mock.onPost(process.env.VUE_APP_IDENTITY_API_URL + 'user/search').reply(404);

    await wrapper.vm.searchUsers(1);
    expect(mock.history.post.length).toBe(1);
    expect(wrapper.vm.users).toBeNull();
    expect(wrapper.vm.pagingInfo).toBeNull();
})
```

this is how my component wrapper is mocked up:

```
const wrapper =  shallowMount(Users, {
  stubs: {
    RouterLink: RouterLinkStub
  }
});
```

does anyone know what the correct syntax would be to register this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add it:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Users, {
  mocks: {
     $toasted: {
         error: () => {},
     }
  }
});
```

Of course you can add more functionality to your mocks.

Comment: I now get ```TypeError: _this.$toasted.error is not a function``` any ideas?

Comment: Try to use Toasted as plugin. Install it like this
`Vue.use(Toasted)`

Comment: in this test Vue is not defined, the test is focused on the component so it errors out as it has no knowledge of 'Vue'. I also tried on the component itself (Users.use(Toasted)) and that also does not work.

Comment: It's my pleasure)